# ckeditor отобразить текст

Tags: ajax, ckeditor

Доброго времени суток, в редактор [`ckeditor`](http://ckeditor.com/) нужно отобразить текст средствами `ajax` к примеру:

```
<span id="text">текст для отображения</span>
<script>
    $('.empty_record').on("click", function(){
        var text_content = $('#text').text();

        $('#editor1').val(text_content);
    });
</script>
```

без редактора в обычный `textarea` такой код работает.

вот собственно и редактор:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

    AjexFileManager.init({
        returnTo: 'ckeditor',
        editor: ckeditor1
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
ckeditor1.insertHtml("Ваш HTML");
```